# Print web articles can one print in ubuntu, as windows

Tags: printing

I have just installed a printer and wanted to test it by printing an article from the web.I am new to linux and most familiar with windows where printing required to right click.

Comment: And have you tried a right click on Ubuntu and what version of ubuntu are you using

Comment: its connected by usb

Comment: i have just installed 18,04 LTS

Comment: @Machar 1) Were you able to print a test page after installation? 2) Can you print a test page now? 3) Can you print by pressing Ctrl-P ?. Please use [edit] to put that info in your question. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use ---> [edit] <---.

Comment: @Machar did I answer well at your question? If yes, tick it as *Accepted*, if not, reply to me (ping me using @) here or below by commenting my answer

Answer (score 0):

There is some way to print from a web navigator :

- using a screenshot
- using the **Print** option (in my case, I will show on Firefox)

---

**Using a screenshot**

Press this combinaison of keys for each screenshot you want to take :

- <kbd>Prt Scrn</kbd> for the desktop
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Prt Scrn</kbd> for the active window (in my case, Firefox window)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Prt Scrn</kbd> for an area you select

The last option can be done with the screenshot software of Ubuntu named *screencast*

NB : If you want to use a print on paper that screenshot, I recommend you to use LibreOffice Writer or Word and include this screenshot inside that document, so you could ajust picture size and location (for example, you don't need an entire A4 page to print a 2 sentences text)

---

**Using the Print option**

just go at top-right corner of Firefox, click on the `≡` icon (NB: it's the setting button), and select *Print* option

You would see your web page like a PDF file, ready to be print